# Preprocess n files concurrently with tf.data API

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I want to use `tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave` to preprocess n files concurrently. `cycle_length` argument is used for this purpose but what is the maximum value of this argument? My CPU has 8 cores and 16 threads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per official docs on [tf.data.experimental.parallel_interleave](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/experimental/parallel_interleave)

> Unlike tf.data.Dataset.interleave, it gets elements from cycle_length
> nested datasets in parallel

and

> cycle_length: The number of input Datasets to interleave from in
> parallel.

So basically, a reasonable argument would be number of dataset elements, which would be processed in parallel. In this way, it has no relation to CPU cores/threads